Group records where value is <5%
I have this table of data in SQL Server:



A
B




11
7.14285714285714


1
0.64935064935064


2
1.29870129870129


1
0.64935064935064


1
0.64935064935064


2
1.29870129870129


1
0.64935064935064


1
0.64935064935064


2
1.29870129870129


129
83.76623376623376


1
0.64935064935064


2
1.29870129870129



where B is the percentage of the total of A.
I would like to group all records where B is <5 into a single line while displaying individual lines for record >5%. In this instance there would be 3 rows of data:



A
B




11
7.14285714285714


129
83.76623376623376


Others
9.0909090909091



I have tried grouping with having but that only returns either >5 or <5 so I would have to union 2 statements.
select b.*
from (
    -- messy sub queries--
) b
group by a, b
having b > 5 


"I have tried grouping with having" - show us!

Seems you just need a CASE expression. Why didn't your attempt work? What was tat attempt?

select case when count(*) > 1 THEN 'Others' ELSE CAST(MIN(A) AS VARCHAR(10)) END, SUM(B) from yourtable group by case when b >= 5 then A end should probably work

select b.*
from (-- messy sub queries--
) b
group by  a, b having b > 5

You could also write SELECT A, SUM(B) FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN B < 5 THEN 'Others' ELSE a END AS A, B FROM yourTable) sub GROUP BY A; Hard to say whether you observe a big difference between all those options. I guess it's more kind of taste what you like.

You can do an aggregation with a case when that puts groups into either A or everything else depending on value of B.
CASE WHEN count(*) > 1 THEN 'Others' ELSE CAST(MIN(A) AS VARCHAR(10)) END creates a correct header. I use COUNT(*) so that we know if we have a <5 grouping (the count should be > 1 there) or not.
SELECT  CASE WHEN count(*) > 1 THEN 'Others' ELSE CAST(MIN(A) AS VARCHAR(10)) END AS A, SUM(B) AS B
FROM
(
    VALUES  (11, 7.14285714285714)
    ,   (1, 0.64935064935064)
    ,   (2, 1.29870129870129)
    ,   (1, 0.64935064935064)
    ,   (1, 0.64935064935064)
    ,   (2, 1.29870129870129)
    ,   (1, 0.64935064935064)
    ,   (1, 0.64935064935064)
    ,   (2, 1.29870129870129)
    ,   (129, 83.76623376623376)
    ,   (1, 0.64935064935064)
    ,   (2, 1.29870129870129)
) t (A,B)
GROUP BY CASE WHEN b >= 5 THEN A END

Output:



A
B




Others
9.090909090909


11
7.14285714285714


129
83.76623376623375




Honestly using a union seems the simplest way to go here:
SELECT A, B FROM yourTable WHERE B >= 5
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Others', SUM(B)
FROM yourTable
WHERE B < 5;

This assumes that the A column is text.  If not, then we would have to add a cast to the first half of the union query.
